# i am converting integers to hexadecimal everything seems fine but the 10 when converted was 0x: instead of 0xa can someone help me?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "\nEnter an integer number: "
answer: .space 8
.text
.globl main

main:
        la $a0, prompt1     #prompt user for integer
        li $v0, 4
        syscall

        la $a1, answer      # load the address of answer into $a1
        addi $t0, $zero, 48 #set $t0 to 48
        sb $t0, 0($a1)          #store 48 at location 0 in $a1
        addi $t0, $0, 120       #set $t0 equal to 120
        sb $t0, 1($a1)          #store 120 at location 1 in $a1
        addi $a1, $a1, 1

        li $v0, 5       #allow for input of integer
        syscall
        add $a0, $v0, $zero #add the input to the $a0 register
        jal print_hex

        la $a0, answer
        li $v0, 4
        syscall         #print out hex answer to console

        j main


print_hex:
        andi $t0, $a0, 0xf
        addi $a1, $a1, 1

        ble $t0, 10, lessThanTen        
        addi $t0, $t0, 39  
    lessThanTen:
        addi $t0, $t0, 48
        sb $t0, 0($a1)
        srl $a0, $a0, 4
        bne $a0, $zero, print_hex
    done:
        jr $ra
```

Comment: Hint: what does the `e` in `ble` stand for?

Comment: When you're commenting your code, things like `set $t0 equal to 120` are basically useless.  We can already pretty much see that from looking at `addi $t0, $0, 120`.  (Although `li $t0, 120` would be even more obvious).  Comments should be one step away from just describing the instruction in machine terms, and describe it in *meaningful* terms like `'x'`.  (Or if your assembler supports character literals as numeric constants, just write `li $t0, 'x'` in the first place and you don't even need a comment, just one on the 2nd store like `#  initial 0x prefix`.

Comment: If you had a specific endianness in mind (MIPS supports both), you could even use `sh` to store both bytes at once, but then your program would depend what endian mode your MIPS was in.  (I think QtSPIM simulates a MIPS that has the native endianness of the host machine, MARS simulates a little-endian MIPS.)